# Start Menu wont work after upgrading to Win 10 build 9926

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

I upgraded Windows 8.1 to Win 10 Preview build 9926, the start menu wont even pop up when I click on it.

I installed classicshell then, it works but after I removed classicshell, the windows start menu still does not work when I click on it.

Does anyone know where the settings are in registry for start menu in Window 10?

Also when I trying to refresh windows in repair mode, it says "drive is locked"...?

Comment: Did you have ClassicShell installed before/during the upgrade?

Comment: If you have the Task Bar set to "Auto-hide", try unsetting that.

Comment: This is a known issue; updates were released to address this problem

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I had classicshell installed before upgrade

Comment: If you log in as a different user, does it behave the same way?  Perhaps try installing the slightly-more Windows 10 compatible 4.2 beta of ClassicShell and uninstall that. Help any?

Comment: tried, start menu wont work no matter who logs in. tried classicshell 4.2, it works well but start menu still wont work after i removed 4.2. I need original start menu working now, worst case i have to do a fresh install again....

Comment: have you installed the latest updates as @Ramhound suggested?

Comment: @RootLoop - You should do a fresh install.  As I indicated this is a known issue, if you install all the updates, and it still doesn't work report the issue to Microsoft so they can fix it.  Outside of waiting there isn't much you can do since a fresh install will likely still have the same problem once you get to the same build you are on anyways. [This](http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-10-updated-18-improvements-included-in-the-latest-patch) update is what I am talking about

Comment: I did a refresh install (enterprise 9926)today and joined into domain. start menu works well under local admin login, but once i login as domain admin, the start menu wont work at all again. I did install the updates tho...nothing helps...also we dont have any gpo applied on existing system to modify startup menu...

Comment: upgrades are always problematic.